# Drive balancing and duplication with mergefs in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, hard-drive, filesystems, storage-pool

I want to use mergefs to create a drive pool in Ubuntu.

Is there any option available on mergefs to pick the drive with the most "relative" free space (the % Free space of the drive) instead of the most "absolute" free space (which is what the mfs policy does, I imagine)? That would provide a more effective drive balance.

Moreover, I am coming from a Windows application called Drivepool which also allow for duplication of important folder. Using this feature, you can have the system to automatically keep some folders data available in more than one drive so to "partially" make it redundant. IMHO this is a great feature. Do you know if this is doable with mergefs somehow?